# Anyone know Multivariate OLS on Statsmodels?

Tags: python, multivariate-regression, statsmodels

I trying to run a mutivariate multiple regression using Statsmodels. Not sure if this is the best tool for this type of regression, so please do tell me if there's another package to which I should belooking. Below is a toy replication of the process (run in Colab).

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

sampleY = {'Maths': [90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20], 'English': [77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 66, 44, 11]}
sampleX = {'Work': [76, 75, 72, 66, 66, 63, 62, 61] ,'Brains': [33, 66, 22, 44, 11, 66, 55, 11]}

Y = pd.DataFrame(sampleY,columns= ['Maths', 'English'])
X = pd.DataFrame(sampleX,columns= ['Work', 'Brains'])

Xc = sm.add_constant(X)

linear_regression = sm._MultivariateOLS(Y,Xc)
#linear_regression = sm.OLS(Y,Xc) - this one works, but of course only with a single DV, i.e. Y = pd.DataFrame(sampleY,columns= ['Maths'])
fitted_model = linear_regression.fit()

fitted_model.summary()
```

However which way I try to ensure that statsmodels is fully loaded - git clone, importing the one module specifically, etc. I get

> AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.api' has no attribute
>   '_MultivariateOLS'

If I run an OLS (i.e. multiple regression, not multivariate), instead, all works fine. Stumped.

Comment: You are not doing something wrong, just what you look for is not there. Please see my answer for a few more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing this (Aug-2019) there is no `MultivariateOLS` in actual terms. That's why the `_` infront of the call; it signifies that it is mostly a placeholder and should not be directly called by a user. Right now, only `MultivariateTestResults` is operational as it acts as the back-end for MANOVA.

I am unaware of commonly used multivariate linear regression implementation in Python. That said, these [lecture notes](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/mvlr-Notes.pdf) on Multivariate Linear Regression by N. Helwig show all the required Lin. Algebra to do it and offer a good walk-through in R; I think they will be very helpful to get one started.

Comment: I add this link for everybody interested in calling R from Python after installing R on the same pc, just in case you wish to use some R libraries within a code written in Python. https://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/using-python-r-together.html

Answer (score 1):

Multivariate OLS is closely related to canonical correlation analysis, which Statsmodels has:

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.cancorr.CanCorr.html

Also, if your multivariate data are actually balanced repeated measures of the same thing, it might be better to use a form of repeated measure regression, like GEE, mixed linear models , or QIF, all of which Statsmodels has.